# jstree - How to enable the folder & file operations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, contextmenu, jstree

In rails 4.2.2, I am implementing a jstree feature. Script is like below,

```
$('#tree').jstree({
 'core' : {
   'data' : {
     'url' : function (node) {
       return '/users/files/treedata.json'
     },
     'data' : function (node) {
       return { 'id' : node.id };
     }
   }
 }
});
```

Generated JSON data is like

```
[{"id":1,"text":"Home","parent":"#","user_id":1,"asset_id":null,"root_node":true,"created_at":"2015-09-15T09:34:15.000Z","updated_at":"2015-09-15T09:34:15.000Z"},{"id":2,"text":"kishore","parent":"1","user_id":1,"asset_id":1,"root_node":false,"created_at":"2015-09-15T09:34:16.000Z","updated_at":"2015-09-15T09:34:16.000Z"}]
```

Referred by https://www.jstree.com

Right now root node & child nodes are displaying with folder icons, how to change the icon for child nodes?

Also how to enable the folder and file operations("contextmenu") feature?

Answer (score 1):

To change the icons of files, we need to specify "type" attribute in json.

```
"type": "itsfile"
```

Now, in the jstree script, you need to enable the **types plugin**

```
"plugins": ["types"]
```

Also, you need to specify that change the icon of all files which has **type** as **itsfile**.

```
"types": {
        "itsfile": {
        "icon": "jstree-icon jstree-file"
    }
}
```

It is the recommended way to do this.

Also, about your second question, you need to enable contextmenu plugin in the same way as we did for types. You need to add **contextmenu** to the plugins array.

I hope this helps you and others.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/):

> To change the icon of the node use the `icon` property.

So, to display custom icons, specify data accordingly.

There is also a trick, if you don't need any icon, specify `icon: false`.

Comment: Ok. Please tell me what should be the value for `icon` because I have already tried by adding this, it wasn't worked. `icon: ??` for both folder and files.